# Store and get value from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `html` page and I'm calling a `javascript` function from the html page and the script is in separate file

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn1" onclick="ButtonClick();">Click Me</a>
<script src="Externalscript.js"></script>
<script>
    Initialize('1,2,3,4');
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myList;  //global variable
function Initialize(ids) {
myList = new Array();
var idList = ids.split(',');
for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
    myList.push(idList[i]);
}
```

I'm storing the ids value in `myList` and now I want to retrieve the myList when the button clicked

```
 function ButtonClick() {
    alert(myList);
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to alert the myList it is giving `undefined`.

How can store the values in a `global` variable and retrieve in other function

Comment: That should work fine, or your `ButtonClick` never got fired. Where do you implement `ButtonClick` function?

Comment: It is firing that's why I'm getting undefined in the alert

Answer (score 2):

`return` the value from function than updating `global-variable` and accessing it

```js
function ButtonClick() {
  var returned = Initialize('1,2,3,4');
  console.log(returned);
}

function Initialize(ids) {
  var myList = new Array();
  var idList = ids.split(',');
  for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
    myList.push(idList[i]);
  }
  return myList;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn1" onclick="ButtonClick();">Click Me</a>
```

**Edit:** To store the result in `global-variable`

```js
var returned = Initialize('1,2,3,4');

function ButtonClick() {
  console.log(returned);
}

function Initialize(ids) {
  var myList = new Array();
  var idList = ids.split(',');
  for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
    myList.push(idList[i]);
  }
  return myList;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn1" onclick="ButtonClick();">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to call my `Initialize` function inside the `ButtonClick()`. I want to call them separately and store the values globally when I call Initialize()

Comment: Is it possible to do the way as I mentioned in my question

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik, How you approach is different than mine ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
<script>
    Initialize('1,2,3,4');
    var myList;  //global variable
          function Initialize(ids)
          {
          myList = new Array();
          var idList = ids.split(',');
          for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++)
                   {
                    myList.push(idList[i]);
                   }
          }

         function ButtonClick() 
          {
               alert(myList);
         }
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn1" onclick="ButtonClick();">Click Me</a>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I just rewrote your code and it prints the list as 1,2,3,4 as expected

Comment: No need to `split` and loop, to fill another array

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble reconstructing the problem. Is this how your code looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="btn1" onclick="alert(myList)">Click Me</a>

<script>

var myList;  //global variable
function Initialize(ids) {
    myList = new Array();
    var idList = ids.split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
      myList.push(idList[i]);
    }
 }

 Initialize('1,2,3,4');
</script>
```

http://codepen.io/calvinclaus/pen/WxNaPX?editors=1011

Because this works...Can you supply a pen with the problem
?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work.

One advice: `split` already creates an array: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

So what you're doing is:

- create an array from a string (`idList = ids.split(',')`)
- loop over that array
- add every value from that array to a other array (`myList.push(idList[i]);`)

Where `myList = ids.split(',');` is enough

Example

```
var myList; 

function Initialize(ids) {
    myList = ids.split(',');
}

Initialize('1,2,3,4');

function ButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert(myList);
}
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', ButtonClick);
```

Working demo: **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oc0ygh40/1/)**